# Make tags behave like workspaces behaviour in xmonad on multiple monitors

Tags: tags, workspace, xmonad, awesome-wm

I recently moved from xmonad to awesome window manager, because I switched to wayland.
In xmonad I remapped the mod+number key to mod + f1-f12.
I had my workspaces named according to my activities i.e. 1:terminal-2:chrome-3:ssh-4:filebrowser-5:thunderbird etc.

In xmonad I would simply press modkey + F5 to show my email-client on whatever monitor was focused. If the email-client is already showing on, another monitor, it will swap it with the workspace that is currently on the focused monitor.

Now In awesome window manager (which truly is awesome), I first switch to an empty tag, make the other monitor the focused one, then press mod + o to move the client to the other monitor, then press mod + Fn to switch my secondary monitor to the desired tag...

Lot's of keypresses which was only one in xmonad.

I was hoping someone could help me out with either 
- some configuration tips to make awesome's tags behave more like workspaces in xmonad
or
- a different approach to how to use this tagging system

Thanks !!

Comment: "I recently moved from xmonad to awesome window manager, because I switched to wayland." - Wait, what?!?

Comment: I read somewhere that xmonad is not working with wayland... (And I switched to wayland, because I had issues using xorg on a bumblebee (Nvidia/Intel) card)

Comment: But... awesome does not work with wayland either...?

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer in itself, but just a "random pointer" that might be helpful. Feel free to downvote, sorry.

https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/5pkc7r/shared_tag_list_with_awesome_4/

Comment: It looks like the answer I have been looking for, thanks (I will mark this thread "solved" once I tried it out)